# Is there a way to automatically fix all ESLint errors in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, eslint

Opened up an old javascript file in a project I'm working on, and there are well over 100 ESLint warnings and errors.  Stuff like

- Missing semicolon
- Unexpected trailing comma
- Expected '===' and saw '=='

Is there a way to automatically fix all these errors at once?  Or do I have to go through and manually fix each one by hand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use eslint cli directly which would be faster, just run `eslint --fix` in the terminal

just make sure you installed eslint globally `npm i -g eslint`

Answer (score 14):

A slight change to the answer to work -as in my case it didn't- would be adding the directory which has the js files which you want to apply linting to, or the file itself .

```
npm i -g eslint

eslint --fix .
```

OR

```
npm i -g eslint
eslint --fix file.js
```